# find this exponential limit

Tags: calculus

I tried turning it into an exp limit and using l'Hopital but I must have done some mistake because the limit to me results infinite whereas the answer is -1, can someone give a hint please

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe include the part with the exp(ln(...))?

Comment: yes I have done that but when I differentiate I get nothing

Comment: Might not matter but is that log base 10 or base e?

Comment: I mean include it in OP so we know where you went wrong

Comment: base e, natyral log

Comment: Are you sure that is pi/2 and not pi/4?

Comment: yes it's written in the exercuse

Comment: You thought it's -1 even though the limit does not exist. Hahahaha. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oDAKKQuBtDo

Comment: Hint: $\frac{\pi}{2} - \tan^{-1}(x) = \tan^{-1}\frac{1}{x}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you start using the identity $$\tan^{-1}(x)+\tan^{-1}(\frac 1x)=\frac {\pi}2$$ $$A=\Big(\frac{\pi}2 - \tan^{-1}(x)\Big)^{\frac 1{\ln(x)}}=\Big(\tan^{-1}(\frac 1x)\Big)^{\frac 1{\ln(x)}}$$ Now, taking logarithms $$\log(A)=\frac{\log(\tan^{-1}(\frac 1x))}{\log(x)}$$ and set $u=\log(\tan^{-1}(\frac 1x))$, $v=\log(x)$. Now $$u'=-\frac{1}{\left(1+x^2\right)  \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}$$ with $v'=\frac{1}{x}$. So, $$A=\frac{u'}{v'}=-\frac{x}{\left(1+x^2\right)  \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}$$ and you probably know that, for small $y$, $\tan^{-1}(y)\approx y$; so, since $x$ is large, replace $y$ by $\frac{1}{x}$ to get $$\log(A)=-\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$$ So, for an infinite value of $x$, the limit of $\log(A)$ is $-1$ and then the limit of $A$ is $\frac 1e$.

Comment: I didn't know the identity in the beginning, can you explain where you got it?

Comment: Well, it is a fundamental trigonometric property; have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions; there very nice properties there.

Comment: ok thanks @Claude

Answer (score 2):

Oh cool. This is very tricky I think.

$\lim_{x \to \infty} (\pi/2 - \arctan(x))^{1/\ln(x)}$

$= (LHR) \exp(\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln(\pi/2 - \arctan(x))}{\ln(x)})$

$= \exp(\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1/(\pi/2 - \arctan(x)) (\frac{-1}{x^2+1})}{1/(x)})$

$= \exp(\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{(\frac{-x}{x^2+1})}{\pi/2 - \arctan(x)})$

$= \exp(\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{(\frac{-x}{x^2+1})}{\pi/2 - \arctan(x)})$

$= \exp(\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{(\frac{-x}{x^2+1})}{\pi/2 - \arctan(x)})$

$= (LHR) \exp(-\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{(x^2 - 1)/(x^2 + 1)^2}{1/(x^2 + 1)})$ (The details I leave to you)

$= \exp(-\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{(x^2 - 1)}{(x^2 + 1)})$

$= 1/e$

Comment: sorry jack i just edited now

Comment: can you see it now?

Comment: @AdmirKullolli okaaaayyyyyyyyyy wait